# Marketing Cloud Cordova Plugin - Inapp notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

We are using Marketing Cloud [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) for sending push messages from Marketing Cloud. When we send the push message, it appears in the notification bar of the phone.

I want to check if we can send the in-app notification within the app with the help of Cordova plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  See https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin#api-reference- for details regarding the handling of button clicks/URLs.